# Renaming shapefiles using Windows Explorer?

Tags: shapefile, windows

I need to rename a shapefile.

Is it ok to simply use Windows Explorer to manually rename each of the three related files that comprise the shapefile?

I am using QGIS.

Comment: This related post may be helpful: http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/126378/8104

Comment: If you're making these changes from the OS, you're not really "using QGIS".  If you get interrupted in the middle of your process, you'll make a mess, which is why ArcGIS allows renaming from the UI.  Are you *sure* QGIS doesn't as well?  See also http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/126378/how-do-i-rename-shapefiles-in-qgis

Comment: It might be quicker to export (save as) from QGIS with the new name then (optionally) delete the old one. Less chance of 'fat fingers' inserting a double space or transposed letters; the consequences of slightly misnaming one of the many files are dire, so I suggest use QGIS to export the files to ensure all components are named the same prior to extension.

Comment: Little known tip: select all files associated with a shapefile in Windows Explorer, press F2 (rename shortcut) then rename one of them.  they'll all rename to the same, keeping their original extension.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is - if you are sure there are no more files associated with it (e.g. .prj file). The associated files have always the same name (prefix).

Answer (score 2):

It is safest and best practice to rename shapefiles in an automated fashion to avoid errors in any of the associated files. You can use the Windows command line [`ren`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490987.aspx) function and a wildcard `*` to easily rename shapefiles and all their associated files. Keep in mind this will rename the original. For example:

```
ren C:\path\to\your\shapefile* renamed_shapefile*
```

Alternatively, you can copy your shapefile and all the associated files to a new location using the [`copy`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771997(v=ws.11).aspx) function:

```
copy C:\path\to\your\shapefile* C:\path\to\another\directory\renamed_shapefile*
```