# Seeking program similar to ArcCatalog in QGIS?

Tags: qgis

i'm qgis user.
There is one inconvenience with using qgis, it's file management.

when i used ArcGIS Desktop, ArcCatalog made me convenience for file management(especially file name change).

QGIS, provide Brower Panel, but it's function so simple.
Can not change file name....

so, when i need to change file name
i must go to folder, and change file name 4 or 5 times(shp, shx, dbf, prj....and so on)

Is there a way to avoid this inconvenience?

Comment: In Windows File Explorer, you can select all parts of the shapefile and rename one of them. The others will be automatically renamed at the same time.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there are some workarounds (maybe outdated) in this post: [Renaming Shapefiles in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/126378/how-do-i-rename-shapefiles-in-qgis).

I have not tried them, I hope it is not difficult to adapt them to the current versions.

The feature request to the developers has been open for three years: https://issues.qgis.org/issues/15791.

It seems to be more an unfavorable feature of the shapefile format than of QGIS.

Some reasons to stop using shapefiles are documented here: https://switchfromshapefile.org/

> - No coordinate reference system definition.
> - It's a multifile format.
> - Attribute names are limited to 10 characters.
> - Only 255 attributes. The DBF file does not allow you to store more then 255 attribute fields.
> - Limited data types. Data types are limited to float, integer, date and text with a maximum 254 characters.
> - Unknown character set. There is no way to specify the character set used in the database.
> - It's limited to 2GB of file size. Although some tools are able to surpass this limit, they can never exceed 4GB of data.
> - No topology in the data. There is no way to describe topological relations in the format.
> - Single geometry type per file. There is no way to save mixed geometry features.
> - More complicated data structures are impossible to save. It's a "flat table" format.
> - There is no way to store 3D data with textures or appearances such as material definitions. There is also no way to store solids or parametric objects.
> - Projections definition. They are incompatible or missing.
> - Line and polygon geometry type, single or multipart, cannot be reliably determined at the layer level, it must be determined at the individual feature level.

---

UPDATE  *(Thanks to [Vince's comment](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/315741/seeking-program-similar-to-arccatalog-in-qgis#comment513489_315743) for making me notice that my answer can be wrongly interpreted):*

QGIS does not have a built-in tool to rename files from its user interface, but it does not seem to be a priority feature.
That in the shapefile format it is necessary to rename multiple files in order not to lose the consistency of the data, is a characteristic of the format itself.
In fact, no file browser application is asked to rename multiple and certain files to maintain the consistency of the data stored in them.
Also, there are no (lame or not) reasons to hate a file format, but to stop using it.

Comment: Blaming the shapefile format for the inability to rename shapefiles in the QGIS UI is right up there with some of the lame reasons to hate shapefiles. There plenty of *valid* reasons not to use shapefiles, but half of them seem to be missing, including, apparently, "QGIS won't let you rename them".